# Executing a javascript function in different computers at same time

Tags: javascript, node.js, real-time, webrtc

I would like to execute a Javascript function in two different computers at same time. I am going to name them as master and slave computer.

The idea is that when I press a button in the master computer, a javascript function is executed in both computers at same time.

Master and slave would connected to an identificative URL like: domain.com/master_idnumberXXX
and master.com/slave_idnumberXXX

So I think I need some RTC protocol or something like that, I have been reading about it but feel a little lost and I would like to know what would be my best option. I've been reading about node.js and similar stuff (webrtc) and for this 'simple' subject I do not know if would be 'too much'.

Thanks in advance and sorry about my un-experience about this field.

Comment: Welcome in StackOverflow.com

Comment: _"I would like to execute a Javascript function in two different computers at same time."_ - Why? What is the function's purpose?

Comment: What is *at same time*? 5 ms? 20 ms? 500 ms?

Comment: @jokerman you can synchronize data between computers either using websocket, socket.io, long-polling, XHR, or browser-to-browser direct data connection i.e. WebRTC DataChannel. You can synchronize timestamp and the invocation time. If you're .NET developer; you may prefer to look at WebSync.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. After reading Muaz Khan reply I think Socket.io is what I was looking for it.

Thanks a lot... by the way is my first time posting here, can't I give karma to comments?

Comment: Ah, master and slave. Because apparently it never occurred to anybody in the 50s or 60s that you might one day find yourself talking to an African American programmer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use WebSocket, though be aware of [potential problems](https://speakerdeck.com/3rdeden/websuckets) (which is a good reason to use [Socket.io](http://socket.io), as already recommended, which provides fallbacks and workaround).

RTCDataChannel leverages RTCPeerConnection to enable peer-to-peer communication of arbitrary data with very low latency -- and as part of WebRTC, it's designed to cope with NATs and firewalls. (More information [here](http://io13webrtc.appspot.com/#36), press P for speaker notes -- apologies for shameless self promotion!) RTCDataChannel is used by the wonderful [Cube Slam](https://www.cubeslam.com) game.

Another option is to use XHR plus the Google Channel API: [apprtc.appspot.com](http://apprtc.appspot.com) uses this for messaging, code [here](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc-samples/source/browse/trunk/apprtc/).

Answer (score 0):

If you use socket.io on a server you can do something like this.

On the master

```
var socket = io.connect();
//button press function
function buttonPress(){
    //do logic
    socket.emit("button pressed");
}
```

On the slave

```js
var socket = socket.connect();
socket.on("button pressed", handlePress);

function handlePress(){
    //do your logic
}
```